# Find Dates - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, netezza

I have the following from and to dates and need to list using a dynamic sql query only the 3 dates that are mentioned below in netezza database

```
   From      To
20120603    20120831


Required Result:     
20120702
20120703
20120801
```

Is there a possibility using dynamic SQL query for netezza that dates in a user specified range can be generated.

Comment: This question isn't very clear at all. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sue I understand your question, but I think you want

```
WHERE From IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes, or `where [From] = ''` as it looks like his dates are strings.

Answer (score 1):

u can try something like

```
select * from table where date in (20120702,20120703,20120801)
```